How to get float currency value from Brick\Math\BigDecimal?
Having brick/money on laravel 11 site I make conversion of currencies like :
$provider->setExchangeRate($baseCurrencyCharCode, $currencyCharCode, $currencyTableRow->value );

$converter = new CurrencyConverter($provider);

$money = Money::of($amount, $baseCurrencyCharCode);
$value = $converter->convert($money, $currencyCharCode, roundingMode: RoundingMode::DOWN);
dd(   BigDecimal::of($value->getAmount())   );

But outputing value I got I see
Brick\Math\BigDecimal {#1678 ▼ // app/Library/Services/BrickMoneyConverter.php:61
    -value: "7340"
    -scale: 2
}

Valid result must be float 73.40. I did not find which method have I to use to get it ? I do not have to worry about scale of currency.
Seems this library knows how to work with scales ?
"brick/money": "^0.9.0"
"laravel/framework": "^11.9",
php 8.2


Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

To get the string representation of a BigDecimal,
just cast it to a string.
If you want to convert it to a float, call the toFloat() method.
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Brick\Money\Money;

$money = Money::of('73.40', 'USD');
$amount = $money->getAmount();

printf('String value: %s<br>', (string)$amount);
printf('Float value: %.2f<br>', $amount->toFloat());

Output:
String value: 73.40
Float value: 73.40

